# Correct use of tense for interview questions?

Tags: tense, past-vs-past-perfect

Q) How did you manage your studies?

Ans (a) I did not study hard. I **had prepared** one timetable and followed it.

Ans (b) I did not study hard. I **prepared** one timetable and followed it.

Which one should be the correct reply for the interviewer question? Why?

Comment: An answer to an interview question should not start "I did not study hard" !

Answer (score 0):

The correct use for this situation is (b) - "I prepared one timetable and followed it"  - When you use "I had prepared one..." you are implying a negation. By this I mean you are implying that something changed.

For example: "I had prepared dinner but my roommate brought home pizza."

Comment: I disagree with this answer.

Comment: "I had prepared" doesn't necessarily indicate negation, it indicates a situation where something happened and later something else happened. "I had prepared one timetable and followed it" would express that there were two steps involved: preparation, and then following.

Answer (score 0):

As @James K said, we should not start with *I did not study hard*.

Both (a) and (b) as they are would not lead to good replies.  Why does following the timetable lead to not studying hard?  I wonder why we are given just these two choices.

If that is indeed the case but we are allowed to elaborate, we could add to (b):

> I did not study hard. I prepared one timetable and followed it initially but realised later that studying hard alone would not lead me to excellence in this fast-changing world; what's more important is to develop the ability to adapt and innovate.

As the sequence of events is clear,  the past perfect is unnecessary and not preferred.